# Removing subViews from uinavigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, subviews

Hi To remove SubViews from UINavigation bar i am using following code.I have  label,button and imageVIew as subView in navigation bar.

```
   for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {


    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

While i am running this it is removing the backGround image of the navigationBar which i added as

```
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImagem imageNamed:@"header-background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

after removing subViews i am adding the background agin,But it is not adding.

Is there any way to remove only subViews of navigation bar without removing the background.

Answer (score 4):

a fast option is to add a value to the `tag` property of the views you want to remove and check for it before removing the the subview, for example, assuming that you add a non-zero value to your subviews:

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if (view.tag != 0) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {

if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
{
  //change your bar image
 }
else
 {
[view removeFromSuperview];
 }
 }
```